# In C return scanf values from function

Tags: c

I am trying to write a subfunction in my calculator program to verify the operands. What I'd like the function to do is return the scanf inputs to the main() function. Here is the code I have used for the sub function:

```
void checkOperand(float f1, float f2)
{
    printf("Please enter two numbers to add, separated by a space: \n\n");
    while( (scanf("%f %f",&f1,&f2)) !=2 ) 
        {
            // you will enter this loop when there is wrong input from the user and there may be garbage characters inputted.
            // eat up each character until buffer is clear indicated by new line
            while(getchar() != '\n')
            {
                continue;
            }
            printf("\nError reading your input. Please try again: \n\n");
        }

}
```

Then, in the main() function here is how I try to call it:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int nChoice = 6; // initialize with an invalid choice
    float fNums1;
    float fNums2;
    float result;

    printf("Welcome to My Handy Calculator:\n\n\t1. Addition\n\t2. Subtraction\n\t3. Division\n\t4. Multiplication\n\t5. Exit\n\n");

    //scanf returns number of successful translations. If user inputs characters instead of numbers, it will not return 1 as you are
    //scanning one value. This is the way to trap the wrong user input.

     nChoice = checkMenuOption(nChoice);

    switch ((nChoice))
    {
        case 1:
            checkOperand(fNums1,fNums2);
            result = fNums1 + fNums2;
            printf("\n\nResult of adding %5.2f and %5.2f is %5.2f \n\n",fNums1,fNums2,result);
            break;
    }
}
```

But the values (f1 and f2) from the scanf function don't get returned back to the main function and when the calculation is performed, it says:

```
"Result of adding 0 and 0 is 0."
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). You absolutely should learn how to use debugging tools (`gdb`, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parameters are passed *by value*. Change your parameters to pass by pointer:

```
void checkOperand(float *f1, float *f2)
```

and

```
while( (scanf("%f %f",f1,f2)) !=2 )
```

In your calling code,

```
        checkOperand(&fNums1,&fNums2);
```

Comment: The forward declaration is defined as follows:
 void checkOperand(float,float);
Do I need to change that too? Because I tried what you suggested and got an error message:
Midterm1v002.c: In function ‘main’:
Midterm1v002.c:27:4: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘checkOperand’
    checkOperand(&fNums1,&fNums2);
    ^
Midterm1v002.c:6:6: note: expected ‘float’ but argument is of type ‘float *’
 void checkOperand(float,float);

Comment: Nevermind. I changed it to:
void checkOperand(float*,float*)
and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you pass float to checkOperand is local value, you must pass float point and Assignment.